# Fastest method to wait under thread contention

Tags: c++, optimization, pthreads, wait

I'm using pthread on Linux. I have a circular buffer to pass data from one thread to another. Maybe the circular buffer is not the best structure to use here, but changing that would not make my problem go away, so we'll just refer it as a queue.

Whenever my queue is either full or empty, pop/push operations return NULL. This is  problematic since my threads fire periodically. Waiting for another thread loop would take too long.

I've tried using semaphores (sem_post, sem_wait) but unlocking under contention takes up to 25 ms, which is about the speed of my loop. I've tried waiting with pthread_cond_t, but the unlocking takes up to between 10 and 15 ms.

Is there a faster mechanism I could use to wait for data?

EDIT*

Ok I used condition variables. I'm on an embedded device so adding "more cores or cpu power" is not an option. This made me realise I had all sorts of thread priorities set all over the place so I'll sort this out before going further

Comment: You must be either horribly misusing these synchronization functions or horribly mismeasuring their behavior to find those kinds of times. Condition variables are about the best you can do, and they're virtually instantaneous. How are you using them and, probably more importantly, how are you measuring?

Comment: I'm using clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time) to measure, both before and after releasing the lock

Comment: Are you by chance getting the end time in the same line/function call that you do the I/O to record it?

Comment: @Eric That just measures how long it was until your thread got the CPU again. That doesn't measure how long it took to release the lock. Likely you had more ready-to-run threads than cores and during those 25 milliseconds, some other thread(s) ran. (You can confirm this by measuring in a thread whose priority is higher than every other thread.)

Comment: If you processing loop takes 25ms, it should not matter what synchro mechanism you use to manage the queue/s of data, (assuming the mechanism works, ie. does not CPU-loop, does not miss pushes/pops).  Lock-release times, interlockedBlahBlah, semaphore calls, condvar waits/signals, context-changes etc. are just a bit of noise in 25ms.

I assume you're pushing/popping pointers/instances in your queues, not copying in/out large structs?

Comment: Oh - another thought - if you regularly have more ready threads than cores, do you have, anywhere, any spinlocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use condition variables. The only faster ways are platform-specific, and they're only negligibly faster.

You're seeing what you think is poor performance simply because your threads are being de-scheduled. You're seeing long "delays" when your thread is near the end of its timeslice and the scheduler allows the unblocked thread to pre-empt the running thread. If you have more cores than threads or set your thread to a higher priority, you won't see these delays.

But these delays are actually a good thing, and you shouldn't be concerned about them. Other threads just get a chance to run too.

Comment: The time period has nothing to do with the lock. The lock was released in the first fraction of a millisecond. The other time was just time the thread wasn't running because the system was doing other things.

Comment: +1 for David - the box is overloaded.  Needs more cores, (possibly more RAM), less CPU-intensive apps.  Also +1 for Billy - 25us, never mind ms, is far too long for just a lock release.